# Is there any difference in meaning between "apply to the company for a job" and "apply with the company for a job"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Would you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *apply to the company for a job* and *apply with the company for a job*? For example:

> I've applied **to** the company for a job.
>
> I've applied **with** the company for a job.

Chat GPT gave me this: *Yes, there is a slight difference in meaning between "I've applied to the company for a job" and "I've applied with the company for a job."
"I've applied to the company for a job" implies that you have applied to become an employee of the company, and that the application has been submitted directly to the company, either through their website, via email or mail, or in person.
On the other hand, "I've applied with the company for a job" can imply that you have applied through a third party, such as a recruiting agency, and that the company is aware of your application through this intermediary. It can also imply that you have some prior relationship with the company, such as having previously worked with them or having a referral from an employee.
Overall, both phrases convey that you have applied for a job with the company, but the preposition used may give a slightly different nuance to the nature of the application.*

Do you agree with its explanation?

Comment: I would not ask ChatGPT grammar questions.  It just parrots back to you things that it's read on the net, but it does not have any real understanding of anything it says and is not intended as a grammar checker.

Comment: No, I do not agree. Chat GPT can generally be counted on for some fairly goofy info. "Apply to the company" is much the better way to say it.

Comment: Please tell me you're not all downvoting this question because the OP showed some research and gave ChatGPT's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT's answer is correct, but misses some key things.

First off, the second sentence is bad grammar, and syntactically, the phrases "to the company" and "with the company" are not parallel.

It's incorrect because we do not apply "with" a company at all.

ChatGPT's answer seems to be based on this correct rephrasing:

> I've applied for a job with the company.

In this format, "a job with the company" becomes a noun phrase, the direct object of "for". "With the company" modifies the noun "job". But in the first sentence, "to the company" is an adverbial that modifies the verb "apply". It describes where the job application was submitted.

Also, ChatGPT leaves out that applying ***to*** a company for a job could mean the company is a job recruiting agency and you don't want a job with that company at all.

You could reasonably use both in the same sentence:

> I applied **to** Acme Recruiters for a job **with** Microsoft.